# AWS Ec2 instance with Nginx Configuration getting 405 for www

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

**https://example.com.au/api** is working but **https://www.example.com.au/api** is not working.

My nginx configurations is like this

```
http {

  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com.au www.example.com.au;

    location / {
      return 301 https://www.example.com.au$request_uri;
    }

  }

  server {
    listen 8443 ssl;
    server_name  www.example.com.au;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/example.com.cert;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/example.com.key;

    location /api {
      proxy_pass https://example_api_service:1001;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
  }
}
```

AWS security groups are like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwbrj.png)

And I have configured the route53 record to my EC2 instance ipv4 public ip.

Please help me to get this done...

Comment: Since there is no `listen` directive for port 443 there must be something missing in your configuration…

Comment: Could you explain how did you configure route53, have you created a record for www.example.au?